# Raspberry Pi 3 not boots if usb camera plugged in

Tags: usb, boot, boot-issues, bootloader

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3

Boots from usb `Ultra Fit` and works perfect. Except it not trying to boot if camera plugged in usb. ACT LED not flashes.

If I remove cam and insert it after boot - OK.

Plugged in devices:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13fe:4300 Kingston Technology Company Inc. USB DISK 2.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. Ultra Fit
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E3372 LTE/UMTS/GSM HiLink Modem/Networkcard
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
```

not starts with ine flash drive+cam. but boots with usb modem+2 flash drives

Is there any way to check bootloader log? Or maybe how to check test points?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is not enough power.

The Pi uses more power during boot than it does after boot.

There is not enough to boot and power the camera at the same time.

Comment: not starts with ine flash drive+cam. but boots with usb modem+2 flash drives.

Comment: If you think that is relevant you should add it to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Throw it out the window and get an Intel Nuc instead. PI in all my experiments is a piece of overpriced, underpowered trash that is good for nothing.

Comment: Intel Nuc is overpriced